# Code prints wrong symbol in wrong format

Tags: c

I need my code to print out

```
Input the number of values: Input the values between 0 and 9 (separated by space): 
your histogram:
0-3
1-2
2-0
etc.
```

but it looks nothing like that? help

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printStars(int n){
   int i;
   for(i = 0;i<n;i++){
       printf("*");
   }
   printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int i,n = 10;
    int input[100];
    int hist[10] = {0};
    printf("Input the amount of values: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Input the values between 0 and 9 (separated by space): ");
    for(i = 0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&input[i]);
   }
   for(i = 0;i<n;i++){
       hist[input[i]]++;
   }
   printf("\n\nYour histogram: ");
   for(i = 0;i<10;i++){
       printf("%d - %d\n",i,hist[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is unclear what you want to achieve. You also forgot to mention what output you expect for which input. And what output yout get.

Comment: Just a hint: `printf` to `stdout` is line buffered. You might not see anything unless you print a `'\n'`.

Comment: The code above, I don't see `printStars` called anywhere.

Comment: It works fine for me: https://ideone.com/B8Fj9z

Comment: @Gerhardh He prints `\n` at the end of every line

Comment: @Barmar Not before he calls `scanf`. He might not see the prompt to input his numbers.

Comment: you must check `n >= 0 && n < 100` first!!

Comment: @Gerhardh I believe that requesting input on `stdin` automatically flushes `stdout`. I see the prompt when I run his program.

Comment: @Gerhardh  You are all absolutely right, my dumbass skewed up the code when copying and pasting. Thank you for your time

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `printStars(int n)` method is supposed to replace count of each number,

e.g. instead of `0 - 3` you would see `0 - * * *`

If this is the case, you will want to change the for loop on line 25 to this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("%d - ",i);
    printStars(hist[i]);
}
```

Also, on line 24, you need an additional \n at the end of the printf to put your 0-count for the histogram on its own line: `printf("\n\nYour Histogram: \n");`

Don't forget to make sure your input is within bounds as well, as you never check if `int n` is within bounds of `input[]`. Speaking of this, why is n instantiated to 10, then immediately scanned into for input without use of `n = 10`?

If you aren't seeing any output on run, try typing input immediately. It's possible that requesting input is clearing the current line printed to.

```
printf("Input the amount of values: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
```

In this case, since there is no \n at the end of the printf and a scanf is immediately called, the input request might be clearing the output line and requesting input. Adding a \n to the end of printf might correct this, if it is the problem you're having.

Other than this, there doesn't seem to be any major problems.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working. What format do you get and what format do you expect ? Personally, I have the

```
0-3
1-2
2-0
```

format